# WCF Rest Service - worked great ... Until SSL

Tags: wcf, rest, iis, ssl

I have a WCF Rest service that has been running very smoothly.  I just got my SSL cert and installed it in IIS, added an auto redirect to https (basically, forcing https).  Now, if I go to "website/ServiceDirectory/Service.svc, I still get the "You have created a service" message, but when I attempt to actually call the service, I'm getting 404 not found.  I have already looked through numerous articles.  I've disabled http/enabled https. I've ensured I enabled "Transport" security in the binding..Not sure if I'm just missing something or what's going on.  Here's my web config, but I'm beginning to think it may be something in IIS

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address=""
            binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebBinding"
            behaviorConfiguration="web"
            contract="EngageService.IEngage" name="win"/>
</client>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="EngageService.Engage1">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
      contract="EngageService.IEngage" bindingConfiguration="WebBinding" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <!--<add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>-->
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

In IIS, the service is configured as an application, and as I stated it was working perfectly before I switched to https.  Does anyone either see something wrong with my config file, or know of any IIS configuration items I may need to check/change?
Thanks

Comment: In IIS7 => features view => SSL Settings, you can turn off the Require SSL option if you add the requirements in the web.config

Comment: I don't know if I really explained it correctly.  It may be better if someone can witness the behavior.  if you go to http://www.aaronsfriedman.com/Engage/Engage1.svc, You will see the service message.  If you go to http://www.aaronsfriedman.com/Engage/Engage1.svc/getquote, you will get a stupid random quote (for testing).  If you then do the same steps but with https, you will still see the service, but get a "not found" error when you try to run the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this boiled down to the protocolmapping section.  It seems that without this mapping, webhttpbinding defaults to http.  Added the webhttpbinding, including the entire section to make it easier to spot - hopefully this helps someone else one day.

```
<protocolMapping>
  <!--<add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>-->
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
  <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="WebBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

If you have tried all of the other articles and still can't get it - try the above.  It breaks http, but I imagine only because you're stealing the endpoint.  If you configured a secondary http binding, I would bet it would work perfectly.